# Virtual field of virtual field in Mongoose 6 with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mongoose 6.12.0. Can I do a virtual field of another virtual field using Typescript?

Here [in the migration guide from Mongoose 5.x](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/6.x/docs/migrating_to_6.html#typescript-changes) I read that `this` is the document type nor any.

Migrating the virtual schema "volume" from Mongoose 5.x to Mongoose 6.x I got this error

```js
const schema = new Schema(
  code: string,
  {
    capacity_id: {
      $type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Capacity'
    }
  }, {
    typeKey: '$type'
  }
);

schema.virtual('capacity', {
  localField: 'capacity_id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  ref: 'Capacity',
  justOne: true
});

schema.virtual('volume').get(function () {
  return this.capacity && this.capacity.volume;
});
```

```
Property 'capacity' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, any, { code?: string; capacity_id?: ObjectId; }> & Omit<{ code?: string; capacity_id?: ObjectId; ... } & { ...; }, never>'.
```